# Can't even open TorBrowser?

Tags: mac

Every time I open TorBrowser on my new 2017 Macbook, it says "Tor unexpectedly exited. This might be due to a bug in Tor itself, another program on your system, or faulty hardware. Until you restart Tor, the Tor Browser will not be able to reach any websites. If the problem persists, please send a copy of your Tor Log to the support team." When I try to restart it, it shows the same result. I tried to delete the TorBrowser data in Application Support but that does nothing. I tried to reinstall Tor in a different area other than Applications but that doesn't help. I can't copy a log to the clipboard because there are no logs. What could be the problem??